# Will a Scheduled Task On Windows Server 2008 R2 work correctly if windows are opened and closed?

Tags: windows-server-2008, scripting, scheduled-task, task-scheduler, batch-processing

I have a batch script that I am currently running on my own Windows 7 computer as a scheduled task.  The task runs nightly when my computer is locked.  The task launches an Progress OpenEdge session which exports data to a file.  Once that is done, the OpenEdge session launches another application through the OS shell which takes the generated data & a master template file to build an output report.

Although the software runs as a task, the application window is still opening and closing each time a report is generated for each data file.  This is just the way the software is written & there is no true batch mode which doesn't require the application Window to not open and close every time.  It appears the application is mimicking User Interface commands automatically.  I have no control over the application that I am calling to generate the report, as it is proprietary software.

So with that said, will a Scheduled Task On Windows Server 2008 R2 work correctly if windows are opened and closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're running the task as the logged-on user's identity (the user who has the machine locked). Provided you have granted appropriate permission for that user to logon locally to the server computer and, provided you configure the Task Scheduler entry the same way as you have on the Windows 7 machine, I wouldn't anticipate any problems.

Progress. *shudder* That's rough...